# How can I get no header but still get "page x of y" in footer?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, lastpage

I'd like to get "page x of y" in a footer on each page, and the way I've found is to use:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

This works but has introduced a solid line at the top of each page and some headers. How do I get "page x of y" without any headers at all?

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to your document preamble. This should remove the header rule.

Comment: I've also flagged both of your "answers", which should be edits to the original question. BTW, welcome at tex.sx!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Regarding the header settings when using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr): In order to remove the header rule, you need to set it to `0pt` using

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Although this is a *length*, it's used as a *command* within the header. In order to clear the entire header, use

```
\fancyhead{}
```

which clears everything (left, centre and right, on odd and even pages).

If you want the mean `\chapter` page (I assume you are using a document class like `book` or `report`), you can set the page style for that specific chapter manually using

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

The reason for this is because `\chapter` (and `\chapter*`) sets the page style to `plain` by default (since the page configuration is different from other pages, with a large open "header"). Here is a minimal example capturing the above:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set default page style to fancy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyhead{}% Remove all header contents
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}% Page X of Y in the footer (centered)
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\thispagestyle{fancy}% Revert 'plain' page style (from \chapter) to fancy
\lipsum[1-25]% dummy text
\end{document}​
```

If you want the page style to be `fancy` *regardless* (or *globally*), and therefore would like to avoid setting to `fancy` manually at every `\chapter`, you could just overwrite the `plain` page style with `fancy` (or create a new `plain` page style altogether; it depends on your usage/preference):

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% Let 'plain' be exactly the same as 'fancy'
\makeatother
```

Add the above *after* setting all the `fancy` header styles, or see section **7 Redefining `plain` style** (p 7) of the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). Note, the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is not necessary; it was merely used for creating dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: Thanks Werner! That works fine. One more thing - how can I get "page x of y" on the first page as well as all the other pages? Thanks again. Harry

Comment: Oops - actually it doesn't work fine. It removes the solid lines at the top of every page, but I'm still getting words in headers in the second part of the document. I'd like to get no headers at all on any page.

Answer (score 1):

I think `scrpage2` is quite a nice package do do things like these. The following creates what you want, plus it leaves a lot of options open.

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\usepackage{lastpage} % enables \pageref{LastPage}
\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{\pagemark of \pageref*{LastPage}}
\ofoot{}
```

For example, you can easily add the current chapter to the top of the page by using `\automark[subsection]{section}` and then e.g. `\ihead{\headmark}`.

Comment: In addtion we have `nccfancyhdr` and `titleps`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful answer on https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3436 .

You could use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` to redefine the plain style, that's described in the [fancyhdr documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). 
For example:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{Lastpage}}
}
```