# how do I add page numbes to a latex document

Tags: page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add “page # of ##” on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document)
>   [How can I get no header but still get “page x of y” in footer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40172/how-can-i-get-no-header-but-still-get-page-x-of-y-in-footer)

how do I add page numbers to a latex document?   I want "Page x of n" format.  I want a simple want to do this.

Comment: Dublicate of [How can i add page # of ## on my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document)

Comment: Have you ever read a small introduction like l2short? Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40172/how-can-i-get-no-header-but-still-get-page-x-of-y-in-footer

Comment: Ah, thanks.  that works.  However, it gives me a horizontal line at the top of the page.  I do not want that.

Comment: @HaroldRosenberger that is because `fancyhdr` is included (it has a default header line), keep reading the answers and you will find your answer. :)